# Trimming batch of videos using timestamp

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to cut multiple videos in folder based on their starting and ending time which is stored in a csv file: annotations.csv

The format of the csv file is:

video_name | starting time | ending time

I think the pseudo code may look something like this:

```
`for i in video_names
 do: cut video according to time frame`
```

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i input.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy output.mp4`

This is something I found for a single video while hardcoding the input names and start and end time.
How can I make this dynamic to correspond with my annotations file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In the below code snippet, just add your path instead of "your_file_path/annotations.csv"

```
pip install moviepy
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
import csv
# name of output file
naming = 'trim_'
def get_sec(time_str):
    """Get Seconds from time."""
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

sample = open('your_file_path/annotations.csv', 'r') 
csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=',')
next(csv1, None)
for eachline in csv1:
    file_name = str(eachline[0])
    out_file = naming + file_name
    start = eachline[1]
    start = get_sec(start)
    end = eachline[2]
    end = get_sec(end)

    ffmpeg_extract_subclip(file_name, start, end, targetname=out_file)
```